# Sandbox mounting confusion

Tags: linux, sandbox, mount, mount-point

First off, I am using [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/projectatomic/bubblewrap) as the sandboxing software, but I feel like it is a general mounting issue, than a bubblewrap one. I am trying to add bwrap into a sandbox wrapper [called sandboxlib](https://github.com/CodethinkLabs/sandboxlib), the details are not important, other than the tests that are run.

One particular test tries to mount the sandbox / from "/foo/bar". This contains 2 sub-directories, data and bin.

The bin directory simply contains a simple binary called 'test-file-is-writable'.

If I run:

> $ /usr/bin/bwrap --ro-bind /foo/bar / --tmpfs /data test-file-is-writable data/1/canary
>
> Couldn't open data/1/canary for writing.

HOWEVER, mounting / as writable works

> $ /usr/bin/bwrap --bind /foo/bar / --tmpfs /data test-file-is-writable data/1/canary
>
> Wrote data to data/1/canary.

However, I am only wanting /data to be writable, and assuming the rest of / to be ro

Adding in a remount as readonly still doesn't fix things

> $ /usr/bin/bwrap --ro-bind /foo/bar / --tmpfs /data  --remount-ro / test-file-is-writable data/1/canary
>
> Couldn't open data/1/canary for writing.

Debugging this further, I added in mounts/paths required to drop into an interactive shell inside the sandbox

> $ /usr/bin/bwrap --bind /foo/bar / --tmpfs /data --ro-bind /lib /lib --ro-bind /lib64 /lib64 --ro-bind /bin /usr/bin --remount-ro / bash

Running a simple ls of / shows everything is mounted as expected. Testing r/w is all fine. The issue, however, is the /data directory is totally empty (other than the output of my 'touch /data/testwrite'). Note the original /data partition I wanted to mount, actually contains files.

Q. Am I not understanding the mounting here? Or are the tests wrong?
My only work around I can see is to copy over files from the original ro /data to the newly write-mounted /data

Answer (score 0):

`data/1/canary` is a relative path and the current directory is not the root directory, so you are trying write to somewhere else